# XCRUD Update data column based on other column's value after edit

Tags: php

I am using xcrud and want to update a column's value (column name PAY) based on column PRICE and column STATUS.

Whenever I edit a row and change the STATUS to "ok" then PAY will be updated with the value of 35% of PRICE. the default value of PAY is 0.

How do I do that using functions.php in xcrud library?